# Breaker does not make solid connection even after replacing it

Tags: electrical

My main box is a 45 year old GE
the bottom 2 THQL1120 20amp breakers both are intermittent.
The breakers have lots of play and don't make solid connections.
Everyone says it's the breakers at fault not the panel.
I changed the breakers with brand new ones and no improvement at all.
So now that i established the fact that it's the panel and NOT the breakers is there anything that can be done with the panel or is total replacement necessary.
Thank you

Comment: Please include the model number of the panel.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. Would it be possible to get a close picture of the breaker mounting point (with the iffy breakers removed)? This might show a mechanical flaw.

Comment: What is the model of your panel? Will it accept the 1/2 inch wide THQP breakers?

Comment: My GE panel accepts both THQP and THQL breakers. The panel has mechanical protections to prevent improper insertion of breakers which prevent the breaker from snapping in if it's not allowed there.

Comment: What brand of breakers are you using?

Answer (score 1):

My panel is a 48-year-old GE Flush Type TX1615F Mod 2.  I have never had a problem with loose contact of breakers. Is it possible that you are not pressing it in all the way?

I have installed a THQL1120GF and a similar 15A, but all my other branch circuits are protected by the thinner (1/2 inch wide) breakers which I think are THQP. If your panel allows these breakers, then try one of these. Two of these would fit in the space of one THQL, right? Their clamp is at a right angle to the clamp for the THQL. If you install only one, put a 1/2 inch spacer next to it.

**EDIT**
My GE panel accepts both THQP and THQL breakers. The panel and the breakers have a mechanical interface to prevent improper insertion of breakers--these prevent the breaker from snapping in if it's not allowed there. I came up against this when I tried to put a 2-pole compact breaker in a single 1-inch slot instead of astride two slots. A THQL must go into a single slot and presumably also has protection from improper insertion *astride* two slots. Are you putting these THQLs in a single slot?